# Using escape function throws js error because special characters are present in text

Tags: javascript

the sample is like this:-

```
var encdata= escape('They're good at coding."Super". Its great!');
```

Now the error comes because it finds the closing apostrophe at they're instead at last.

It will work if i code the same as

```
var encdata= escape('They re good at coding."Super".Its great!');
```

Similarly if i use double quotes and give like

```
var encdata= escape("They're good at coding."Super".Its great!");
```

It will throw error at "super" but not at they're.

So, it should work when my text contains both double quotes and apostrophe.

And i can't wrap my text within as 'text' or "text".

So, i need an alternate solution for it

Comment: escape has also been replaced with encodeURIComponent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 1):

[Escape the characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Escaping_Characters) with `\'` or `\"`;

```
var encdata = escape('They\'re good at coding."Super".Its great!');
var encdata = escape("They're good at coding.\"Super\".Its great!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use \" or \':

```
var encdata= escape("They're good at coding.\"Super\".Its great!");
```

or

```
var encdata= escape('They\'re good at coding."Super".Its great!');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a slash `\` to escape the apostrophe inside the single quotes, or alternatively the open quotes inside the double quotes.

```
'They\'re good at coding."Super". Its great!'
"They're good at coding.\"Super\".Its great!"
```

This is true for almost every language ever. Adding a slash to characters lets it know that you want it to be a literal character instead of having a special meaning.